# Ajax response handling not working under Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, firefox

Well, that's quite a strange issue :

I'm sending an Ajax POST request to some php script and wait for the response :

```
var data = $('#'+frm).serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data
}).done(
function(r){
   alert("Process ID :"+r);
}
);
```

The problem with that is : it **does** work under Chrome, but it does **NOT under Firefox**.

What could be wrong?

---

*(**hint :** I've checked it out with FireBug and there seems to be absolutely no issue with the response; it comes in as it should)*

---

**UPDATE**:

- Tried adding an error handler (`.fail()`) but with success
- Also tested it under **Safari** : it works there too.

---

Thank you a lot guys! The issue was probably having something to do with caching :/ - after I deleted recent history, it did work. - Case closed.

Comment: What is the response? Also, set up an error handler (`fail()`) and see if it fires and what gets passed to it.

Comment: What does the js console say about the javascript itself? Maybe there's an error that's causing js to abort.

Comment: @Utkanos The response is just a number, that's all. As for the error handler, I added that too; but since there seems to be no issue with the request itself, it didn't help.

Comment: @Matt The console says nothing : no errors, no warning, nothing. Just a... successful post request (along with its response) :/

Comment: Is the number that the response is returning 0? Maybe the version of FF you are using has a bug that sees 0 as a failure. Try changing the response to something like {"num":0}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was probably having something to do with caching :/ - after I deleted recent history, it did work. -

Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery's `$.post()` method. You're doing it anyway, just with `$.ajax()`

```
$.post(url, {
    data: data
    }, function(r) {
        alert("Process ID: " + r);
    }
);
```

Comment: With respect, there's no reason this would help with whatever issue the OP is having. `$.post`, as you say, merely delegates to `$.ajax` anyway.

Comment: @Utkanos unless Chrome is fixing something in OPs script that Firefox isn't.